# Arranging objects in special way

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, extremal-combinatorics

Imagine there is a cinema hall and there are $n$ seats and we want to arrange $n$ people with some special conditions on our seats.
Each people have number from $1$ to $n$ and clearly our seats is numbered form $1$ to $n$ either and now consider these conditions.

$\color{blue}i)\color{blue}{\text{Each people can sit on his number seat and even in his multiple seats}}$, for example, person with number $1$ can sit in all of our seats and person with number $3$ can sit on seats with number $3, 6, 9\dots$

> Now We want to $ \color{blue}{\text{arrange these people in the way that minimize seated people}}$ in this cinema.

For example, our cinema have $6$ seat's and we have $6$ people (note that the number of people is the same with seats)so in order to minimize seated people we have to arrange people in this way.
Person number $1$ has to sit in seat number $5$ and person number $2$ has to sit in seat number $4$ person number $3$ has to seat in seat number $6$ in this way persons numbers $4, 5, 6$ can't in the cinema because their seats are full.

So how can I find the minimum number of seated people in the cinema and minimum number of seats required if a condition is given as if my above example?

Comment: There is a more confusing way of phrasing this question in terms of functions finding the minimum $|S|$ such that there exists $f:~S\to [n]$ where $S\subset [n]$ such that $s\mid f(s)$ for all $s\in S$ and $t\nmid r$ for any $t\in [n]\setminus S$ and $r\in [n]\setminus f(S)$.

Comment: Do you require that the ones that cannot be seated be the last ones in the list?  For example, if $n=14$, we can put $1$ in seat $13$ but then we can $11$ will have to get his seat, so only the last three cannot be seated  We can put $7$ in $14$, $6$ in $12, 5$ in $10$ so at least four are not seated in total.

Comment: If $n=24m$, we can put people $6m+1$ to $12m$ in even seats $12m+2$ to $24m$, and odd-numbered $4m+1$ to $6m-1$ in triple their number, so $7m$ people are not seated.

Answer (score 0):

I can keep out $37\%$ of people this way:
1. For $N/16<m\leq N/8$, put $m$ in seat $4m$ and $2m$ in seat $8m$.
2. For $N/4<m\leq N/2, 4\nmid m$, put $m$ in seat $2m$.
3. For odd $N/6<m\leq N/4$, put $m$ in seat $3m$.
4. For odd $3N/20<m\leq N/6$, put $m$ in seat $5m$.
5. For odd $N/8<m\leq3N/20,3\nmid m$, put $m$ in seat $5m$.
6. For odd $N/8<m\leq N/7, 3\mid m$, put $m$ in seat $7m$.
This unseats $2/16+3/16+1/24+1/120+1/120+1/336=157/420$ of the people.
You still have the first $N/16$ people to seat as well.
You can't do better than $1/2$ because everyone shut out has someone sitting in their chair.

Comment: For $N/68<m\leq N/34,4\not|m$, you can put $m$ in seat $17m$ and $2m$ in seat $34m$, to unseat person $17m$ which is another $3N/272$ people.

Answer (score 0):

People from n/2 to n can seat only on one place, so if you seat people from 1 to n/2 on their places, n/2 people will have no place. Am i wrong? Intuitively i think you need to prove that you cant do better than 1/2 of all people

Comment: If there are two primes between n/2 and n, you can't unseat both, because the only person to unseat them is person 1.